# Indempodent and involution matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a problem I don't know how to solve, any help is appreciated.

Let C be an involution.
Define: $E=\frac12(I+C)$ and $F=\frac12(I-C)$

Show that E and F are both idempotent and $EF=0$

Well since C is an involution $C^2=I$

But I don't really know how to get started

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, note that
$$
4EF = (I+C)(I-C) = I^2 - C^2 = 0\\
4E^2 = (I+C)^2 = I + 2C + C^2 = 2I + 2C = 4E
$$

Comment: In the first part don't you mean 2EF instead of 4EF?

Comment: Oh wait I'm stupid, I see it now